# JS Select2: option not selected (only first time)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2

I'm using angularjs, jquery and select2.
I have a datatable with filters, each filter is a select2 box.
The results are filtered server-side, and the ajax request is triggered by the selection of the filter (in other words when selecting a select2 option).

The problem is the following: in some circumstances when i select the filter the option in not added in the select2 box and the request is sent without that filter. This happens only the first time, so if I select that option again the behaviour is as expected.

I tried hard to debug and I've been for hours inside jQuery and select2 code without understanding much.

What I would like to know is a good strategy for debugging, if there is any tool that can help me comparing the two executions (when I select the option for the first time and the second time) or any good idea that can help me.

Comment: I'm trying to understand which event triggers the ajax call. If I understand your post correctly, your are using the `select2:selecting` event. Have you tried using `select2:select` or a `change` event?

Comment: I managed to debug it by attaching a DOM break point on the subtree modification of the div containing the select2 input box, what i would like to know is if there is a tool to fast analyze the differences between the two executions (when I select the option for the first time and when I select it the second time) since, theorically, they should start from the same application state